# Retain Dropdown value after fileupload in MVC 5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I creating a file upload project in MVC. In form i have dropdown and file-upload control. i use file-upload control through partial view. whenever i try to upload file i lost my dropdown selected value.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlChain_Hotel", (SelectList)ViewData["ChainHotel"], "Select Chain", new {  @class = "form-control" })
```

**Partial View**

```
<input type="file" name="file_Uploader" class="form-control uneditable-input" />
<input type="submit" id="btn_upload" value="upload css/js" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Comment: How are you setting the value as selected in your `SelectList`?

Comment: I had same problem. I used to store the Dropdown list in Session["MyDropdown"] and then post back to the View from controller in a ViewModel after upload.

Comment: @mxmissile  `ViewData["ChainHotel"] = new SelectList(db.chains, "chain_id", "name");`

Comment: You need to post your controller method